# Get the total increments using the cumulative sum counted from a meter which sometimes resets

Tags: dolphindb, accumulate

I have counted the cumulative sum from a meter, and saved them in a column `cl` of table "t”. After a while, the meter will be reset.

I want to get the total increments using the cumulative sum counted from a meter in a specific period of time. The only method I know is using the statement `select  max(cl)-min(cl)  from  t`, but it doesn’t work when the data within a certain time is cleared. How can I get the expected result in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `deltas` to calculate the differences between two adjacent cumulative sums first, then specify the `where` condition as `delta > 0` to calculate the `sum(delta)` for a specific period of time, for example:

```
t=table(1 2 3  7 0 1 3 6 8 0 5 as cl)
select sum(delta) from (select deltas(cl) as delta from t) where delta>0

// output
sum_delta
---------
19
```

It returns "19", which is the sum of “6”, “8” and “5”. I hope it helps you.